# Passing data to another page causes the value to change to null

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have been trying to get the cartTitleList & cartPriceList of the MainPage to move the values into the Page3 cartTitle1.Text & cartPrice1.Text but each time I try, values on the Page3 Lists are null

I have tried 
Parametrized Constructors
Properties
Methods

MainPage.CS (This Current one uses Method as the way to transfer the data)

```
        List<string> cartTitleList = new List<string>();
        List<string> cartPriceList = new List<string>() { "0", "0" };

 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cartTitleList.Add("Test1");
            cartTitleList.Add("Test2");
            cartPriceList.Add("Test3");
            cartPriceList.Add("Test4");
            bool i = cartTitleList.Contains("Test1");
            if (i == true)
            {
            Page3 cartDetails = new Page3();
            cartDetails.Datainput(cartTitleList, cartPriceList);
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
            }
        }
```

Page3.CS

```
        List<string> cartTitleListDisplay = new List<string>();
        List<string> cartPriceListDisplay = new List<string>();


        public void Datainput(List<string> testList1, List<string> testList2)
        {
            cartTitleListDisplay = testList1;
            cartPriceListDisplay = testList2;
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BuyChange();
        }
```

This is were the Null Exception Errors Occur (Null On the List)

```
        private void BuyChange()
        {
            cartTitle1.Text = cartTitleListDisplay[0];
            cartPrice1.Text = cartPriceListDisplay[0];
        }
```

Comment: How is this related to UML? Looks more like a possible bug report to some Mickeysoft tool?

Comment: I removed UML tag

Comment: @qwerty_so That's my mistake I was meant to write UWP

Answer (score 0):

The `Frame.navigate(typeof())` method will navigate to a new instance of `Page3`, not the instance that you created. That’s why you get a null value in the `Page3`. The `Page3` instance you see is not the same one that you created.

Generally, we use [Frame.Navigate(Type, Object) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-19041#moniker-applies-to) to pass parameters between pages.

You can create a small class that includes all your parameters and pass an instance of the class, like this:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class Parameters
{
    public List<string> cartTitleList { get; set; }
    public List<string> cartPriceList { get; set; }
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cartTitleList.Add("Test1");
    cartTitleList.Add("Test2");

    cartPriceList.Add("Test3");
    cartPriceList.Add("Test4");
    bool i = cartTitleList.Contains("Test1");
    if (i == true)
    {
         Page3 cartDetails = new Page3();
         //cartDetails.Datainput(cartTitleList, cartPriceList);
         Parameters myParameters = new Parameters();
         myParameters.cartPriceList = cartPriceList;
         myParameters.cartTitleList = cartTitleList;

         this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page3), myParameters);
    }
}
```

Page3.xaml.cs

```
static List<string> cartTitleListDisplay = new List<string>();
static List<string> cartPriceListDisplay = new List<string>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var parameters = (Parameters)e.Parameter;
    cartTitleListDisplay = parameters.cartTitleList;
    cartPriceListDisplay = parameters.cartPriceList;
}

private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BuyChange();
}

private void BuyChange()
{
    cartTitle1.Text = cartTitleListDisplay[0];
    cartPrice1.Text = cartPriceListDisplay[0];
}
```